# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds?

Tags: php, sql

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'like= 1 where ID =57'` at line 1

This is the code with update, all names of attributes and table are checked.

```
<?php
    include("../connect.php");
    if (session_id() == "")
    session_start();
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $update = "Update  komentari  set like = 1 where ID=$id";

        if (mysql_query($update)) {

            echo 'success';
        }
        else {
        echo    mysql_error();


        }

    ?>
```

Comment: `like` is a [MySQL reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html).... if you have to use it as a column or table name, then you must enclose it in backticks (`)

Comment: LIKE is a reserved word. Use Backticks to escape

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3):

`like` is a reserved word. You cannot use it "raw" in the query. Try this instead:

```
UPDATE komentari SET `like` = 1 WHERE ID = $id
                     ^----^---note the backticks
```

Full list here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Tnx ,it works now :-)

Answer (score 3):

`like` is an SQL reserved word. You'll need to either use a different column name, or quote it with backticks as `` `like` `` whenever you refer to it.